# Devise Installation Not Working

Tags: devise, rubygems

I am trying to install the devise gem but when i use the command
rails g devise:install
i get the error message :

Could not find generator 'devise:install'. Maybe you meant 'responders:install', 'simple_form:install' or 'scss:assets'
Run `rails generate --help` for more options.

can anyone assist me in rectifying this issue?

Comment: have you run `bundle install` after adding devise gem in Gemfile?

Comment: yes i have done that

Answer (score 0):

Try to to solve this by deleting my Gemfile.lock, doing `bundle install` again and then stopping spring with spring stop I could then call the generator without root privileges

OR

Try command:

```
sudo rails generate devise:install
```

Comment: im trying the first option now

Comment: its still not working @puneet18 i am still getting the same error

Comment: have you tried `sudo rails generate devise:install`

Comment: i cant use sudo becuase i am running on windows

Comment: There is no sudo command in Windows. The nearest equivalent is "run as administrator." You can do this using the runas command with an administrator trust-level, or by right-clicking the program in the UI and choosing "run as administrator."

Comment: try 1. `gem uninstall devise` 2. `gem uninstall warden` 3. `bundle install`

Comment: thank you it worked now after trying the last option @puneet

Comment: Great. Accept and vote my answer if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

This is mostly a typo if you copied it from the github repo.
I had a similar issue.

1. Make sure you added the gem in the gemfile as `gem 'devise'`
2. Run in your project directory: `rails generate devise:install`